# Set height of a div in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue js . I want to set one div based on another div height, with pure javascript. the problem I am facing is I can't set the height using pure java script. but I can set it using jquery. can any one please help me to change this jquery to javascript . the code I am using is given

```
 Vue.nextTick(function () {
            var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('filterSection').offsetHeight;
            $(".searchResultSection").css("max-height",`calc(100% - ${offsetHeight}px)`);
           });
```

I need to change the jquery part into java script.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, `computed properties` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) is the perfect option to solves your problem:

**Declare a computed property** who will return the filterSectionHeight

```
export default {
  name: "App",

  computed: {
    filterSectionHeight() {
      const filterSectionDOM = document.getElementById("filterSection");
      return filterSectionDOM ? filterSectionDOM.offsetHeight : 0;   
    },
  }
};
```

**Define your div `filterSection` and `searchResultsSection`** in your component (or App component), don't forget to **add a `:style` attribute** who handle the dynamic `max-height` provided to `.searchResultsSection` in your template

```
<div id="filterSection"></div>
<div class="searchResultsSection"
     :style="{
            'max-height': `calc(100% - ${filterSectionHeight}px)`
     }">
</div>
```

**Set height of each div to 100%** in your css

```
#app {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#filterSection {
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple; //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_A._Meyer
}

.searchResultsSection{
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

You will find a full demo here > https://codesandbox.io/s/1rkmwo1wq

Comment: I have tried this strategy, but the computed property is not reactive: `filterSectionDOM ` is `undefined` and hence I get `0` back. The same thing happens when using `refs`. I guess the only solution left is watching for content changes and changing 'manually' some variable representing f.i. the height.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the context of this change, but I'll try to give you some solutions based on best practices on how to achieve that:

1. If parent element has a fixed height, then children with `height: 100%` will adopt parents height.

   .parent {
   height: 200px;
   }

   .child {
   height: 100%;
   }
2. Use a vue-directive for DOM manipulation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html
3. Use v-bind:style="height: `calc(100% - ${offsetHeight}px)\`" on the element that you want to achieve the height!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the javascript DOM-style to do this.
Try this.

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
   var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('filterSection').offsetHeight;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("searchResultSection");
   x[0].style.maxHeight = "calc(100% - ${offsetHeight}px)";
});
```

Comment: I try this solution but one error is showing "vue.min.js:6 ReferenceError: calc is not defined"